# How to display a single json data which received as a http response from nodejs in service using angular?

Tags: html, angular, angular6

Im making a http request in service file & it returns a json response.
     My response :

```
                           [{ Key : 122,
                          "Record" : { "Id" : 111,
                                             "Name:"aa"}}]
```

I need to display it in my html.  Im saving this response in data.

I have tried using,

```
       <div class="form-group"   *ngIf="data">
       <input type ="text" [value] = {{ Id }}
       </div>
```

But Im getting undefined in the textbox.
Can anybody tell me what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is not correct. It should be

```
 data =  [{ Key : 122,Record : { Id : 111,Name:"aa"}}];
```

If it is a JSON string

```
[{"Key":122,"Record":{"Id":111,"Name":"aa"}}]
```

This needs to be converted to JSON using JSON.parse() method.

To access Id

```
<div class="form-group"   *ngIf="data">
   <input type ="text" [value] =  "data[0].Record.Id">
   </div>
```

Check working code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aerk1f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: thank you . It worked for me.. I have upvoted @ranjeet8082

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response contains errors. Its not a valid json format.
Your JSON response should start with Object, Not Array of Object

```
{
    "Key": 122,
    "Record": {
        "Id": 111,
        "Name": "aa"
    }
}
```

You can use ngModel and assign to property. 
Also You can use one-way databinding to display values in html.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lc7y74

Comment: That is my mistake. If json format format is like you mentioned, how to display it in html? Could you please tell me?

Comment: Is there any harm in getting an array of JSON object from the API call?

Comment: There is no harm in that. You can use array if you want. But Standard way of JSON response is object with property, those property can contain array of items.

Comment: So you mean to say, if he gets more than one object, he needs special handling to handle one object / multiple objects. Additionally that is JSON API specification which wraps the data in an object `{data: <your_data>}`. Hence, you need to wrap the object in data attribute of your JSON if you plan to follow the specs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

the following code will work if you store the http response in data variable ,the response should be arrary with one element as you want to show first element only.

if data is 
```

```
data = [
        { 'Key' : 122,
          'Record' : { 'Id' : 111,
                       'Name': 'aa'
                     }
        }
      ];
```

```

```html
<div *ngFor="let d of data">
  <div class="form-group" *ngIf="d">
    <input type ="text" [value]="d.Record.Id">
  </div>
</div>
```